# Angular freshness strategy fetches data also from cache

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, caching-strategy

On Angular docs the service worker `freshness` strategy is described as following:

> freshness optimizes for currency of data, preferentially fetching requested data from the network. **Only if the network times out, according to timeout, does the request fall back to the cache.** This is useful for resources that change frequently; for example, account balances.

I implemented this strategy in my solution:

```
// ngsw-config.json

"dataGroups": [{
    "name": "jokes-cache",
    "urls": [ "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/" ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "performance",
      "maxSize": 5,
      "maxAge": "1d"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "stocks-cache",
    "urls": [ "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock" ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 10,
      "maxAge": "1d",
      "timeout": "5s"
    }
  }]
```

But when I check the Network tab of the DevTools, I can see that not only the network call is triggered, but also the local cache is accessed:

[image]

I would expect to see only the network call for the "stock" endpoint and no access to the cache (the response comes way before the 5 secs timeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot looks correct. The gear icon near the second request does not mean accessing the cache - it just means that this network request was performed from the service worker (which is intended behavior in that case).